# Is a true contradiction possible in FOL?

Tags: logic

((S⇔M)∧(M∧¬M)⇒(S∧¬S))

If I were to provide evidence that the premises (S⇔M) and (M∧¬M) were undeniably empirically true, then does that not mean that the conclusion (S∧¬S) MUST be true according to the rules of FOL? How can a contradiction be true? I have looked up dialetheism but due to my lack of experience using formal logic I cannot come to understand the implications. What would it mean if I proved this sentence in the real world?

Comment: How does a snake eating its own tail make its stomach both full and empty?

Comment: I see how you could say the stomach is full, depending on what you define as a "tail," but I fail to see how it would be empty...

Comment: That's too vague an analogy I guess. My overall question, though, is what happens when you find a contradiction that is empirically true? If I were to provide physical evidence of a "tautological contradiction" what does that say about the logical language I am using?

Comment: Ronald Reagan sells marijuana to babies that recite Gregorian chants backwards.

Comment: You didn't find a real contradiction. You just need to stop doing so many drugs.

Comment: The snake question was just an analogy... I'm asking what does it mean to find a true contradiction in the real world. What kind of implications would that have?

Comment: If we find a contradiction that appears to be empirically true, it generally means that one of our axioms or assumptions that led to the contradiction is false. In your case, the assumption that a snake that eats its own tail has an empty stomach is possibly the culprit...

Comment: Thank you for that Richard, but ignore the snake thing for now... What if I found a statement where all the premises are empirically true and the conclusion is empirically true and provable, but is a contraction.

Comment: Adding "empirically" doesn't change anything. There is no such thing as a world where the scenario you describe can happen.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine but I have found such a statement, so what does that mean? Am I using the wrong formal language?

Comment: You may as well be asking us "what if I discover empirically that $1+1 \ne 2$".  It's a nonsensical question.  The answer is "you won't".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely, if you were to demonstrate that $S \iff M$ and $M \wedge \neg M$ were both true, then $S \wedge \neg S$ would also be true. But $M \wedge \neg M$ is *already* a contradiction, so this is neither surprising nor a problem.

If you think you've found an example of $M \wedge \neg M$, then you've incorrectly translated a natural-language sentence into formal logic. $\neg M$ *must* mean literally "$M$ is not the case"; there is absolutely no situation - physical, mathematical, or otherwise - in which both $M$ and $\neg M$ can be true.

Comment: If such a case were ever to be found would that imply that our understanding of logic and mathematics is flawed?

Comment: Anyone who claims to find such a case should be counted as a crackpot. The sane thing to do if it seems like $M\wedge\neg M$ is true is to conclude that your assumptions, your deductions, or both, are flawed.

Comment: @GregG Such an example *cannot* be found. What all of the commenters are pointing out is that it's nonsensical to suggest that one might be. For example, suppose I claimed to have found a bachelor who was a married man - you would not conclude that I'd discovered some deep logical contradiction, you'd just realize that I didn't really understand what "bachelor" means. Likewise, if you were to show me something you thought was a "true contradiction", all that could possibly prove is that you're not using the correct definition of "contradiction".

Comment: @Reese I've cleaned up the statement to better represent what I've found.

(S⇔(P∧M))∧(¬(P∨M)∧S)

I have found a case in the real world where both sides of the conjunction are true, yet the truth table of this statement comes out as all false, a contradiction. I've shown my overall argument to a number of philosophy professors at my University and they have told me that my reasoning for why each side is true, is sound. 
So other than "it can't be true because it can't be true" what do you make of this?

Comment: @GregG Have you told your professors that you're looking at this with regard to *first-order propositional logic*? If so, and they agree with you that $(S\iff (P\wedge M)) \wedge (\neg(P\vee M)\wedge S)$ is an accurate translation of your example into first-order propositional logic, then they're simply wrong. They may be thinking of another logic, in which the symbols $\iff$, $\wedge$, $\neg$, and $\vee$ mean something different, or in which a propositional variable ($P$, $M$, or $S$) is not required to be a precise statement with a defined truth value.

Comment: @Reese Well I got each side translated and verified by a different instructor, so one verified that (S⟺(P∧M)) is true when I apply the definitions of S, P and M. And others agree with me that (¬(P∨M)∧S) is undeniably true as well. So all I did was put them together with a conjunction and these two true statements became a contradiction. I'm afraid to show the whole formula to any one person for fear of getting a reaction like the ones I saw on here, but from my peers or superiors in my own field.

Comment: I can't see how this is possible BUT I refuse to accept "it's not true just because it's not true" because I have evidence that it may actually be true.

Comment: @GregG It's important to note that I am *not* saying "it's not true just because it's not true". I'm saying "it's not true because the meanings of the words prevent it". Going back to the "bachelor" example; a "bachelor" is *by definition* an unmarried male; I can therefore dismiss out of hand any claim to have found a married bachelor, because that defies the meaning of "bachelor". Likewise, any claim to have found an example in which $(S \iff (P\wedge M))\wedge(\neg(P\vee M)\wedge S)$ holds can be summarily dismissed, because that would defy the meanings of the symbols.

Comment: @GregG To address the issue of your professors: I strongly suspect that, at least subconsciously, you're presenting the problem slightly differently to each of them, so they're interpreting the symbols $P$, $M$, and $S$ slightly differently. For example, say I took a pea-pod with three peas inside, showed it to someone and asked "Is this one thing?" They would almost certainly say yes. If I then showed it to someone else and said "is this three things?" they'd also say yes, because now they think by "things" I mean "peas". I *cannot* therefore conclude that $1 = 3$.

Comment: @Reese May I email you my complete argument so that you may be able to give me more specific feedback? It's exactly one paragraph in length but makes up for in its content what it lacks in length.

Comment: @GregG Absolutely. I'm hesitant to post my email address willy-nilly, but my webpage can be found on my profile and my email address is given in the Contact Me section.